# Jmeter - Could not read JMeter properties file

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to pass a value in jmx from the command line but i'm getting this error.

```
An error occurred: Could not read JMeter properties file:C:\test.properties
```

Command:

```
jmeter -p C:\test.properties -n –t C:\test.jmx
```

Comment: you are missing space after file name: `.properties -n`

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you don't have enough permissions in order to read the file in the root of system drive, there are following options available:

1. [Run command prompt as Administrator](https://www.howtogeek.com/194041/how-to-open-the-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8.1/), in this case you should have access to the file
2. If you cannot do the point 1 - copy it somewhere else, i.e. to your [home folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory)
3. If points 1 and 2 cannot be done (i.e. you don't have admin rights)  - put all the properties from the *test.properties* file to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)
4. Provide all the properties via [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

   ```
   jmeter -JpropertyName1=value1 -JpropertyName2=value2 -n -t ...
   ```

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems there is problem in reading your file.

1. Try to keep your properties file inside some folder.

   For example: You can keep properties file in below location:

```
C:/users/somefolder/test.properties
```

2. See if you have to use forward slash `/`:

```
C:/test.properties
```